# Is 4.5.1 also in-place upgrade of 4.0 and 4.5?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

Now we have .NET framework 4.5.1. Just curious to know whether the 4.5.1 is also an "in place upgrade" for 4.0 and 4.5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is, check [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5a4x27ek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) at MSDN:

> The .NET Framework 4.5.1 is an in-place update to the .NET Framework
>   4.5. The .NET Framework 4.5 and .NET Framework 4.5.1 replace the .NET Framework 4. When you install these versions on a system that has the
>   .NET Framework 4 installed, the assemblies are replaced.